# Intervention Image resize() not working two times

Tags: laravel-5, intervention

I am using Laravel 5 and i have integrated intervention with it i am trying to resize image in two differnet sizes but the save function is saving images in one size only here is the code of my controller

```
$image = Input::file('image');// Getting image
    $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //Getting Image Extension
    $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renaming image
    $img = Image::make($image);
    $medium_image = $img->resize(25,25);
    $large_image = $img->resize(50,50);
    $image->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    $medium_image->save('uploads/medium'.$fileName);
    $large_image->save('uploads/large'.$fileName); // uploading file to given path
```

The intervention is only sizing the image with bigger dimension it is re sizing the   second image with the same dimension can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was resizing and cropping (fit) but the final image is still the same as original. Found out that I had to add function encode, to produce the manipulated image

```php
return $image->encode('jpg', 80);
```

In your case try to save the encoded image to those variables

```php
$medium_image = $img->resize(25,25)->encode('jpg', 80);
$large_image = $img->resize(50,50)->encode('jpg', 80);
```